# Why is freshly obtained token showing expired in Postman?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization, bearer-token

**UPDATE: Turns out that everything is working EXCEPT in Postman. When I turned on Swagger it worked there, and running it through RestSharp it also works.**

We have a web API where you request a token, then pass that token in the auth header.  It is working in one version of the site, but failing in another on the same server:

[image: Token Fetch Call]

[image: Ensuing call using provided token]

Weirder still, every call to the second function gives the exact same expiration date and time.  We have a separate function to test which has an authorization on the function, not the controller, and that one works successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Probably an issue setting the "expiration time" claim when generating the token or if it's running on some web engine you might be rewriting the auth token from a cookie.

Comment: Apologies for questions, just trying to figure out how to fix:
If it was being set wrong, why would it show the correct expiration time?
I am using Postman - would there be cookies involved?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).